# Scala: How can i dynamically specify conditions on a function that copies files

Tags: scala

I have a function that moves all the files in `src` to `tgt`. Now i want to add a third parameter, that is for example an array of functions with conditions which files in `src` should be excluded. Each of the functions should return a boolean, indicating if the file should be moved or not. The functions should be something like: do not move if the file starts with "_".

How can something like this be implemented in scala?

Comment: When you say dynamically you mean that you want to change that behavior at runtime?.   There may be hundred of possibilities to develop this program. Have you tried any code to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use the advantage of having functions as first citizen:

```
def method(src: String, tgt: String, filters: List[File => Boolean])
```

you can then pass whatever function you want to use as filter.

```
method("path/to/folder", "path/to/destination", List(_.getPath.startsWith("_")))
```

specifying the type on the list you can easily write the value:

```
List[File => Boolean](
  _.getPath.startsWith("_"),
  _.getName.contains("foobar")
)
```

The method should run all the functions using and expect true in all of them. For that you could look into "reduce" the list

```
filters.reduce[File => Boolean] { case (a, b) =>
  file => a(file) && b(file)
}(yourFile)
```

As per @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez notes, it makes more sense to use forall in this situation:

```
filters.forall(p => p(file))
```

Which will run all the conditions and expect to be true for all of them... a lot easier :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this solution with the reduce function only work in the case of two functions? Is there a way of doing the check with x functions?

Comment: @Joha the idea of the `List` is that it will work with any number of functions... did you at least take a look to what the code is doing and tested it? - Anyways, FerranJr, great answer. One little suggestion, you may use `exist` or `forall` instead of a `reduce`. For example `if (filters.forall(p => p(file))) moveFile(file)`

Comment: Yes, i tried to understand. What does the case (a,b) => mean? i thought a and b stands for the two functions

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez good point, using Booleans the forall would make a lot of sense!

Comment: @Joha 
case (a, b) =>
is pattern matching on elements of the list in groups of 2...
so, as we have a list of functions, both a and b are functions that require the File as parameter... and you define how do you want to combine them